# How to write ng-repeat for following JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**My Template code:**

```
        <tr ng-repeat="row in dataList">
          <tr ng-repeat-start="row in dataList[$index].data" ng-if="dataList.data.[columnDisplayData[$index].colName].showRow">
```

My **Json Data Object**:

```
{
   "reportId":1,
   "tableData":
     [
      {
         "data":{
            "data":[
               {
                  "Comp Set(Group)":{
                     "showRow":true,
                     "row":{
                        "sunday":7.1,
                        "saturday":19.1,
                        "total":"19.3",
                        "tuesday":23.4,
                        "weekend":"19.9",
                        "weekday":"19.0",
                        "friday":20.7,
                        "thursday":23.2,
                        "wednesday":23.4,
                        "monday":17.9
                     }
                  },

                  "%C(Transient)C":{
                     "showRow":true,
                     "rowName":"per_C_ransient_C",
                     "row":{
                        "sunday":"-15.5",
                        "saturday":"18.9",
                        "total":"-4.5",
                        "tuesday":"-14.4",
                        "weekend":"12.6",
                        "weekday":"-11.4",
                        "friday":"6.4",
                        "thursday":"2.1",
                        "wednesday":"-21.2",
                        "monday":"-7.8"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "hotelName":"XYZ"
      },

     ...

   ]
}
```

I want to use `ng-repeat` for **data** array then later `ng-repeat` of `hotelName`.
    Firstly, `ng-repeat` on **hotelName**, then data of same jsonObject.
    Please, suggest me about this.

My expected format should be like, below mentioned in table,

```
hotelName               
Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Weekday
data    data    

hotelName                           
Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Weekday

hotelName                           
Sunday  Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Weekday
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What are the values of sunday, moday, tuesday etc you want because it is present everywhere in your JSON. See the sunday,monday etc instance is present in each key like My Property(Group),Comp Set(Contract),%C(Transient)C  etc...Which one do you want?

Comment: Firstly there should be ng-repeat on hotelName , and then on "data" jsonObj andd agaain it should go for another jsonObj.

Comment: But your data object contains sunday,monday etc on many keys as mentioned above in my comment. Which sunday,monday etc values you want?

Comment: There are columns of sunday,monday,tuesday etc so, every sunday monday will be in respective sunday,monday column

Comment: But sunday.monday etc for each hotel are present in "%C(Transient)C" and "Comp Set(Group)". Which one do you want?

Comment: Actually I  unable to tag image,otherwise I will show you the format.consider, 1st row will be of %C(Transient)C & 2nd row will be of  Comp Set(Group)

Comment: You can see my code right?Just tell me , how nested ng-repeat will be applicable? AND columnDIsplayData contains  "%C(Transient)C" and "Comp Set(Group)" on JS file.

Answer (score 0):

use this function in controller and call that `$scope.arr` in `ng-repeat`

---

$scope.arr = new Array();
$scope.setData= function(){

```
for(i = 0 ; i < $scope.dataList.tableData.length ; i++){


    for(j= 0 ; j < $scope.dataList.tableData[i].data.data.length ; j++){
        $scope.arr[i] ={"hotelName":$scope.dataList.tableData[i].hotelName , "days":$scope.dataList.tableData[i].data.data[j]['Comp Set(Group)'].row};
    }
}
```

}

---

**View  :**

Hotel
        Monday
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
        Friday
        Saturday
        Sunday
        Total
        Weekend
        Weekday
    
    
    
    {{data.hotelName}}
    {{data.days.monday}}
    {{data.days.tuesday}}
    {{data.days.wednesday}}
    {{data.days.thursday}}
    {{data.days.friday}}
    {{data.days.saturday}}
    {{data.days.sunday}}
    {{data.days.total}}
    {{data.days.weekend}}
    {{data.days.weekday}}

Comment: you should fix some of your formatting. Otherwise the answer looks good and should work in theory. I hope the answer works out and they are able to move along with the project.

Comment: Thanks Avnesh, but what about ng-repeat on html?

Comment: @ShubhamDeshmukh now check it ... I have made little changes .

Comment: @Raj,JS part is working, but this is what I am writing on HTML,,     <tbody ng-repeat="row in data.hotelName">     
 <tr>{{data.hotelName}}</tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="rows in data.days">                                         <td style="text-align: center;">{{data.days.sunday}}</td>   . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

You have a little misunderstanding in `ng-repeat`.

You can pass to later `ng-repeat`, objects that have been parsed from previous one `ng-repeat`; so if you have something like:

```
$scope.data = {
    key1: {},
    key2: {}
}
```

writing this in your html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in d">
        {{key}}: {{value}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

means: "Hey Angular, in the first `ng-repeat` give me all the object who are in `$scope.data` and create a `tr` for each one; then, in the second `ng-repeat` give me all the keys and the related values of the object that you gave me in the first `ng-repeat` and create a `td` for each one"

Anyway, to reach your goal you need to nest some table in your table as in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8TsZZS1fVngZAekCLAlr). In this way you can get the view you want with your json.